# sudo password not working while in tmux session

Tags: macos, sudo, tmux

When I open up the terminal on my Mac OSX Ventura and do sudo, my password works perfectly fine. However when I enter any tmux session and try sudo the password won't work. Keeps saying incorrect password. Can anyone please help me why it's behaving that way and what can I do to fix/investigate this?

Comment: I had a similar issue with tmux through git bash, but I also found a similar bug outside of tmux, so now I'm not sure if it's just me tripping over keys when I enter my password too quickly.